# Innodb Table not able to execute any DML operations in MySQL-5.6.23

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I am facing a strange issue for an innodb table with mysql-5.6.23, I have two DB instances configured in master-master setup, all live traffic is being served by one instance at a time , suddenly one particular innodb table stops executing DMLs and all queries referring that table gets stuck. Below are the details of table size and innodb config parameters

```
Table details
12K     ERP_INSERT.frm
325M    ERP_INSERT.ibd

Innodb Config Parameters

innodb_data_home_dir = /usr/local/mysql6/data
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:100M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 40
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 40G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 100
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

I have tried using unlock tables, flush tables but lock on table don't get released, finally I restarted MySQL instance to remove this lock.
Please help me to find out what is causing this issue and how to mitigate the same.

Snippet from show engine innodb status

```
---TRANSACTION 21674675426, ACTIVE 0 sec
3 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 12733500, OS thread handle 0x7f6d0ad35700, query id 1411990346 172.10.17.60 99user cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 21674675430, sees < 21663148509
---TRANSACTION 21674609895, ACTIVE 46 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 39 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 26 row lock(s), undo log entries 19
MySQL thread id 12728923, OS thread handle 0x7f6d67924700, query id 1411781698 172.10.17.65 99user update
insert into navintegration.ERP_INSERT (STATUS, USER_HOST , DB_NAME , TABLE_NAME , PKEY_NAME ,PKEY_INDEX , DATE_TIME  ) values ('N','ERP','property','PROFILE','PROFILEID','2846937','2016-01-15 17:18:44')
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 21674609896, sees < 21663148509
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 46 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 117 page no 18348 n bits 544 index `PKEY_INDEX` of table `navintegration`.`ERP_INSERT` trx id 21674609895 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 235 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 6; hex 323834363936; asc 284696;;
 1: len 4; hex 007f1837; asc    7;;
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  What was the last query before things became "stuck"?

Comment: Hi Garima ma'am, Is there any particular error message on DML operation ?

Comment: DBAs would be in a better position to answer this question.

Comment: what say : SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

Comment: @Rick : RAM on system is 128 GB and total innodb tables are of 310GB

Comment: @Aman : No there is no error message but query gets stuck and so it keep on running

Comment: `TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 46 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED` ... `PKEY_INDEX` of table `navintegration`.`ERP_INSERT` -- What _other_ transaction is running?  Do you use `autocommit=OFF` and failed to issue `COMMIT`?

Comment: @Rick I can't see any other running transaction in processlist so this is little weird for me. autocommit is set to ON .

Comment: It could be `BEGIN; do some SQL; do some non-SQL; ... COMMIT;`  The processlist may be showing that the other transaction is busy with non-SQL stuff.